# Call Aura from LWC event not working with LWR community

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, experience-cloud, google-analytics, lwr

I am trying to dispatch event from lwc  to listen in aura , inorder to implement google analytics. However aura is not able to catch event in the LWR community . however it works fine for Aura site

Comment: This doesn't seem surprising to me given that LWR doesn't support Aura components...

Comment: @PhilW is there a way to track Google analytics only via lwc as it doesn't seems to be working for LWR